# An American expression for "a packet of crisps"

Tags: american-english, expressions

[image]

According to the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, it seems that this is called "a packet of crisps" ([Lognman | crisp](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/crisp)), but the same dictionary says that "packet" is British English. ([Longman | packet](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/packet)) I would like to know what native speakers of American English would call the picture above.

**[Edit]** The first time I saw the picture, I thought native AE speakers would call it "a bowl of potato chips", but according to the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, a bowl is "round" ([Longman | bowl](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bowl)), so I am assuming that "a bowl of potato chips" does not work.

Comment: That's a bowl of crisps, not a packet.

Comment: American usage is dominated by [***bag of chips,***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bag+of+crisps%2Cpacket+of+crisps%2Cbag+of+chips%2Cpacket+of+chips&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) but British English are as likely to use [***packet of crisps*** or ***bag of chips***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bag+of+crisps%2Cpacket+of+crisps%2Cbag+of+chips%2Cpacket+of+chips&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3). Nobody uses ***packet of chips*** much. Note that BrE ***chips*** are AmE ***French fries***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have (to my shame) bought packets of 'ridge cut' smoky bacon flavour Walkers crisps (when I was working in a Civil Service office with a canteen); they looked like the ones in the picture. To me, in the UK, _packet of crisps_ and _bag of crisps_ are both equally valid. As you say, 'chips' are what foreigners call them. In France they are _pommes chips_, and guess who eat _Kartoffelchips_?

Comment: Why are so many commenters averse to submitting them as reasonable answers?

Comment: @DelphicOracle Time to change your name if you've got to ask. :-)

Comment: @DelphicOracle - some 'old hands' here have an aversion to submitting fully-fledged 'answers' to what they perceive to be trivial questions which could have been easily answered by the OP doing some research. Such answers are often downvoted on our ELU sister site.

Comment: I'm not an American, but I've heard Americans say a bag of chips. Also you can say "bag of crisps" in the UK. However, I suspect most Americans will know what "packet" means. This is not only a British word. Also a packet of crisps in the UK is most commonly a small 25g serving of crisps, not a larger sized bag.  Packets are generally small, and bags/packs are generally larger.  This is true in both US and UK English. I suspect it's not typical for Americans to buy crisps in such small packets .

Comment: The dictionary is misleading. It quotes the common phrase _packet of crisps_ but, as Stuart says, shows a picture of a bowl of them, presumably so that you can see them clearly!

Comment: WRT to this being a packet or not - 'packet' can be used as a dimensional quantity, i.e. "this is a packet of crisps, poured into a bowl" as opposed to say, "half a packet"

Comment: As often, your dictionary is being overly specific for the sake of being easily understandable, with the consequence of being technically wrong. Round bowls are round; most bowls are round; but not all bowls are round.

Comment: Wait, @FumbleFingers, is your NGram suggesting that BrE today accepts _chips_ to mean what AmE calls _crisps_ instead of what AmE calls _fries_? I "a bag of chips" synonymous to "a  packet of crisps" or are the items in the bag actually fries?

Comment: @terdon: No - we go along with *tortilla **chips*** (and maybe ***corn** chips*) because they came from America, and they're not made of potato. And we have *potato **snacks*** for a wide variety of (usually, highly processed) potato-based "nibbles". But traditional British potato crisps (from Walkers, etc.) are rarely if ever called "chips" by actual natives.

Comment: As it stands, the title of this question and the image in its body ask for two different things. It would be nice if it were edited, since right now it's not clear at a glance which answers address the question correctly.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149955/discussion-on-question-by-kaguyahime-an-american-expression-for-a-packet-of-cri); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 22):

As an American I would say that's a bowl of (potato) chips. If I wanted to be specific I would say they're wavy potato chips or "ruffles". You can drop the word "potato" since that's what people will assume when you say "chips". We do not call them *crisps* here.

While bowls are usually round (all of mine are), they don't have to be. See for example this ["Square Cereal Bowl"](https://www.macys.com/shop/product/the-cellar-whiteware-20-oz.-square-cereal-bowl-created-for-macys?ID=519750&pla_country=US&CAGPSPN=pla). If it's supposed to be used in the same way a round bowl would be used, it's still called a bowl.

A packet (or *bag*, which is the word I would use) of chips is something else entirely. See for example this [bag of chips](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Lay-s-Classic-Potato-Chips-8-oz-Bag/33282303); the bag is made of some foil material and is airtight before you open it.

Comment: Note "ruffles" is a genericized brand name. Some pedants (or lawyers) might object to the use if the chips are a different brand, but it's mostly fine.

Comment: "We do not call them crisps here" It might be worth noting that Pringles are called 'crisps' and labelling them (or similar products) as 'chips' is false advertising in the US.

Comment: @JimmyJames except that everyone just calls those "Pringles" (even the off-brand ones).

Comment: Personally (AmEng) I would not assume potato chips if someone mentioned bringing chips to a party.  Tortilla chips would seem equally likely.

Comment: @JimmyJames I knew I smelled lawyers: *The US Food and Drug Administration weighed in on the matter, and in 1975 they ruled Pringles could only use the word "chip" in their product name within the phrase: "potato chips made from dried potatoes". Faced with such a lengthy and unpalatable appellation, Pringles eventually renamed their product potato "crisps", instead of chips.* — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pringles)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149957/discussion-on-answer-by-laurel-an-american-expression-for-a-packet-of-crisps); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

[image: An image of an opened bag of potato chips next to a front-on view of a similar unopened bag.]

The above image shows an opened bag of potato slices (that have been sliced thin and deep-fried) next to an unopened bag.

In the UK, these bags would each be called a "packet of crisps".

In the US, these bags would each be called a "bag of chips".

---

The image you have included from [Longman Dictionary's definition for "crisp"](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/crisp) seems to be intended as an example of the potato "crisps" themselves, and not as an example of a "packet of crisps".  More specifically, that image depicts "crisps" in a serving bowl.

Comment: In the UK, we can use either 'bag' or 'packet'; we are not confined to just 'packet'.